# mobx: react app rerender everytime a property changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, mobx, mobx-react

Say my entire react app listens to a single store. That store is an MobX observable. `mobx.observable(someVeryLargeObjectContainingAllTheStates)` So the design is like Redux's single store.

Does the whole react app rerender everytime a single property change in that store? Meaning `render()` is called recursively on ALL components?

Comment: No, MobX is efficient in that an observer will register every single observable value it dereferenced, so a component that relies on `state.myValue` will only re-render when `state.myValue` changes, not when another observable value on `state` changes.

Comment: @Tholle so in this way, is it more efficient than Redux? How does Redux know which store properties a component listens to?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to say MoX is more efficient than Redux for every case. There are a lot of awesome optimizations in the `react-redux` library for not doing unnecessary updates. Both MobX and Redux can be a nice fit depending on your use case.

Comment: ok, do u knowhow does Redux know which store properties a component listens to?

Comment: Redux does not know anything about React. Same goes with Mobx. These handle state management. It's the corresponding "binding libraries", mobx-react / redux-react that bridge the stores and the UI (React).

Mobx creates a dependency graph for observers to know when to react. (Components are turned into observers).

Redux does not do that. It does shallow comparison. People will have to couple an immutable library with Redux and implement shouldComponentUpdate (pureRender).

It means that *by default* you will have better performance in an Mobx powered React app with much less hassle.